# Can I configure Eclipse to suppress the "is not used" warning for a specific fieldname?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

For ease of development, my team has the following code in every java class:

```
/**
 * The logger instance.
 */
private static Logger LOGGER = new Logger(Foo.class);
```

Not every class actually logs something, though, so sometimes this `LOGGER` goes unused, complete with Eclipse warning. We have this for when we need it to log something for debugging purposes or info purposes. The result is that we have a number of classes where there are no other Eclipse warnings apart from this one. We could add annotations to suppress these warnings, but that would involve touching a lot of files for no real benefit other than fixing eclipse warnings.

Ideally, what I would want to do is set a rule that states "IF the unused field is named `LOGGER`, THEN suppress the "field is not used" warning." Is this at all possible?

Comment: I think this applies here: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Comment: There is no support for doing this.

Comment: Make the field protected instead of private.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Doesn't that have other side effects, like it being accessible by outside members as well?

Comment: Isn't your LOGGER defined the same throughout your system?  You could define it as public in one place, if you want.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc not exactly. Foo is the class that Logger is defined in. We call the LOGGER constructor with the current class as sole parameter so the class that sends the logging message is also logged in our logs. Once my coworkers are back from vacation, I might discuss redesigning how we log things, but until then, I'm just looking for a way to get the compiler warnings away without having to edit every class that constructs a logger.

Comment: @QBrute not this isn't YAGNI, this is going to be needed later and it's always annoying to write it manually because it had to be deleted because it is unused or remove annotation for no reason.

Comment: I don't know how to configure this directly in Eclipse IDE but you can specify the compiler option: "-warn:-unused" for the Eclipse compiler. Then there will be no warnings for ANY UNUSED CODE - so beware!
Therefore I wouldn't recommend to use it for this usecase. In our company we use this for some old legacy modules where these kind of warnings aren't important.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `@SuppressWarning("unused")` ? You can refer to [Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%252Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%252Ftasks%252Ftask-suppress_warnings.htm)

Comment: As I said, I could add annotations to suppress this warning, but there are potentially hundreds of files that I would have to add this annotation to, which would pollute our subversion changelog. I would prefer a solution that involves changing Eclipse preferences, but without a blanket disable of all unused warnings.